# Problem with foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1005

I am getting error #1005 - Can't create table (errno: 150).

I have been through the checklist of:

- both tables are InnoDB
- the columns are the same type (INT)
- attributes are the same (UNSIGNED NOT NULL)
- the collation is the same
- I have tried with indexes on the foreign keys, it still doesn't work (and they shouldn't be needed for MySQL 5)

Comment: Have you any data in the `lang.id` column?

Comment: still the same error with the data removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my syntax. Instead of

```
REFERENCES `table`.`col`
```

it should be

```
REFERENCES `table` (`col`)
```

This question can be deleted.